# how to create two new lists from this mix in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create two new lists one for colors and one for sizes.
So I want the new code to be:

```
resp["colors"] = ["Teal Combo", "Teal Combo"]
resp["sizes"] = ["s","s"]
```

So far, no dice.

```
resp = {}
resp["color"] = ['Color:', 'Teal Combo', 'Size:', 'S', 'Color:', 'Teal Combo', 'Size:',        'S']


for i, s in enumerate(resp["color"]):
    colors = []
    sizes = []
    print i , s
    if s.lower() == 'Color:' and len(resp["color"]) > i+2:
        colors.append(resp["color"][i+1])   
        sizes.append(resp["color"][i+2])
    resp["colors"] = colors
    resp["sizes"] = sizes
```

Comment: Assumably `resp` (in the first part of this question) is a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = resp["color"]
i = 0
colors = []
sizes = []
while i<len(data)-1:
    d = data[i]
    if d.startwith("Color"):
        colors.append(data[i+1])
        i += 1
    elif d.startwith("Size"):
        sizes.append(data[i+1])
        i += 1
    i += 1

resp['color'] = colors
resp['size'] = sizes
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. anyway to solve this using a python module?

Comment: @slopeofhope: If you're sure about the structure of the `resp['color']`, then: `resp={'color':resp['color'][1:4:len(resp['color'])], 'size':resp['color'][3:4:len(resp['color'])]`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to turn an iterable of alternating values into an iterable of pairs.

In your case, you're using a sequence (a list), so we can do it by slicing and zipping:

```
color = resp['color']
pairs = zip(color[::2], color[1::2])
```

The `::2` means "a slice starting at the beginning, ending at the end, and picking every 2nd element", while `1::2` means the same thing but starting at element 1 instead of at the beginning.

If you wanted to work with any arbitrary iterable, you could do it like this:

```
color = resp['color']
icolor = iter(color)
pairs = zip(icolor, icolor)
```

This is a special case of the more general [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) function in the Recipes second of the `itertools` docs, or in the third-party [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) library:

```
pairs = more_itertools.grouper(resp['color'], 2)
```

If you want to understand [how grouper works](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html), click the link.

---

However you do this, you'll end up with pairs like this:

```
>>> print(list(zip(color[::2], color[1::2]))
[('Color:', 'Teal Combo'),
 ('Size:', 'S'),
 ('Color:', 'Teal Combo'),
 ('Size:', 'S')]
```

---

Once you have those pairs, this should be easy:

```
resp['colors'] = []
resp['sizes'] = []
for name, value in pairs:
    if name == 'Color:':
        resp['colors'].append(value)
    elif name == 'Size:':
        resp['sizes'].append(value)
```

Or, if you want to do it more generally:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, value in pairs:
    result[name].append(value)
resp['colors'] = result['Color:']
resp['sizes'] = result['Size:']
```

Or even:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, value in pairs:
    name = name.rstrip(':').lower() + 's'
    result[name].append(value)
resp.update[result]
```